# how to get the metadata of files stored in alfresco content management system?

Tags: lucene, content-management-system, classification, alfresco, web-crawler

Hi i have stored some files(pdf, html,doc) in alfresco cms, my requirement is to classify these files using metadata "content-type" filed in the alfresco cms, is it possible to do it by using only alfrensco or do i need to integrate any other crawlers(tika, nutch, lucene) with alfresco to get it. please suggest me a way to do it

Comment: Does Alfresco already pull out the metadata you want? e.g. if you go into Share, look at the document details page, and view the document properties / metadata, does that have all you want?

Comment: yes i can view the metadata from file properties, i have changed my question, i need to classify the files using this metadata

Comment: Classify in what manner? And how do you want information out? Ie. do you want that the documents go to specific folders on import, depending on content-type, or ie. you want to know how many PDF docs do you have in the repository?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have stored different types of docs(html,pdf,doc) in cms so by using the docs metadata i want to store all pdf files in my local system folder and all html files in another folder like that i want to clasify based on file type

Answer (score 2):

Hi This is a simple Rule to move an HTML file to another folder.

If you need more flexibility and just 1 rule instead of a rule for each type, you'll need to write some JavaScript and check on the mime-type field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "content-type" metadata are based on the extension of filename put in Alfresco (.pdf, .doc). Files with un-recognized extensions have no valid content-type.

You can simply use "Rules" in Alfresco to organize your files.